# How to do url redirects in single html file app using Electron

Tags: javascript, redirect, electron

I currently have a web app using one index.html file for everything. The server rewrites requests such as /settings/billing to index.html and my javascript detects the window.location.href to determine what module to load. It works well and is fast.

But, now I'm creating a Desktop app using Electron. And things are a bit fubared now. My app will sometimes trigger a browser load of a new page using window.location.href = "example/page". And that obviously doesn't exist in the file directory. The problem is now I don't have a server that can rewrite the url request.

So, how can I handle this in Electron? I need all url requests to point to index.html.